# Googlesheet > Script > PDF > Drive ---> exclude script buttons

Tags: pdf, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I did a script to save my spreadsheet into a pdf in My Drive but... the PDF includes the script-bound buttons.

How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

(the text editor has a problem, my intro is missing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cu7M.png)

Comment: You can programmatically copy the sheet and then strip out the script-bound buttons before converting it to a PDF. [Review the App Script reference documentation for the Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) to figure out how to programmatically manipulate script-bound images.

Comment: This is exactly what is what I've done: my script copies one single sheet into another spreadsheet and then saves as a PDF, but I don't know how to strip out the script-bound buttons. Any leads?

Comment: You'll find the solution in the documentation. Just spend sometime reviewing it and you'll find what you need.

Comment: Trust me I'm on this sheet since 48h without sleep...Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I found a workaround solution

Comment: Have you checked the documentation thoroughly? Trust me, the solution you're looking for is definitely in there. **Hint:** Check the `Sheets` and `OverGridImage` classes.

Comment: I found this `var images =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getImages(); for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { images[i].remove(); }` there is one image I'd like to keep... so I spent another day on this.... I don't find any solution for single image –

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var images = sheet.getImages();
var img = images[0];
img["delete"](); // this one
```

I just repeat it for each image like this:

```
  var i4 = x[3];
      i4.remove();
  var i3 = x[2];
      i3.remove();
  var i1 = x[0];
      i1.remove();
```